# Getting my head round Java graphics

Tags: java, graphics, groovy, awt, basic

I am trying to do some very simple and crude graphics stuff with Java (deliberately crude and simple as it emulates a computing environment from 1980/1981).

The Java (Groovy in fact) code runs some very simple BASIC:

```
10 REM Testing Plotting
20 FOR X = 0 TO 31
30 LET Y = SIN(X/10)
40 PLOT (X, 11 - Y * 11)
50 NEXT X
```

Plot is provided in Java/Groovy like this:

```
grafix = textArea.getGraphics()

    ....
def plot(def x, def y)
{
    grafix.fillRect(x * 20 as Integer, y * 20 as Integer, 20, 20)
}
```

Now the code works after a fashion - I briefly see a sine curve flash on the screen but it disappears almost instantaneously (presumably on next repaint of the text area). How can I get the graphics to stay there - the only way I can think of is to save the plots (and unplots) into a list and then have that "play" every paint - but that seems quite an extreme solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
textArea.getGraphics()
```

Don't do that.  The graphics instance is momentary.  Instead paint the component when told to do so (by overriding `paintComponent(Graphics)`).

Comment: This shows the general idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722242/adding-a-watermark-to-a-jtextarea

Comment: Not sure either of these suggestions works with a dynamic environment - I want to be able to have the graphics change as the BASIC changes

Comment: Yeah, just draw the graphics in paintComponent and call repaint() on your component

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin not sure it will help, but I got bored and wrote some groovy to render to the background of a viewport containing a JTextArea https://gist.github.com/2979500

Comment: OK, I still do not see how any of this can helping a scripting/dynamic environment. In effect the drawing needs to be done at run time - it's not known at compile/write time.

Comment: *"do not see how any of this.."* ..Is a comment to me.  Are you replying to @tim_yates?

Comment: Both actually! I still do not see how I can use an override of paintComponent to do dynamic plotting/unplotting - except maybe by applying the command pattern? i.e. I could save the plots and unplugs in a list and rerun them every time? Though I think that would end up  over-writing any text that might be on the window... hmmmm

Comment: *"Both actually!"* Now I review your 'question' I realize I guessed a question & answered that based on your statements, since you failed to ask a question.  What is your (one) question?

Comment: "How can I get the graphics to stay there - the only way I can think of is to save the plots (and unplots) into a list and then have that "play" every paint - but that seems quite an extreme solution."

Comment: Another alternative better for that case.  Use a `BufferedImage` & display it in a label, make the changes to the image then repaint the label.